# Filldraw square in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to filldraw a square with sides 7sqrt(7). I am not getting the desired output.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw(0,0) rectangle (7*\sqrt{7},7*\sqrt{7}); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\sqrt{x}` is for typesetting the symbol for the square root of x. To perform a calculation, you have to use the `pgf` function `sqrt(x)`. And to not confuse the coordinate parser (which looks for a `)` as the end of the coordinate), any calculations that include parentheses have to be wrapped in `{}`, to hide them from the coordinate parse. Hence you get the expression `({7*sqrt(7)},{7*sqrt(7)})` shown in hpekristiansen's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw(0,0) rectangle ({7*sqrt(7)},{7*sqrt(7)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: square]